# Column 'id' not found. I need it to return a unique id

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem with my database, I need it to insert a database every time
insert a unique id in the return

the error is here, `resultSet.getInt("id")` it is not returning a unique id

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SIGN_SHOP_TABLE_NAME (
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,                                  
    `location_x` DOUBLE NOT NULL,                                 
    `location_y` DOUBLE NOT NULL,  
    `location_z` DOUBLE NOT NULL, 
    `location_world` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
    `item` TEXT, `amount` INTEGER,  
    `sell` DOUBLE, 
    `buy` DOUBLE, 
    `custom_item` BOOLEAN NOT NULL, 
    `countdown` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

this is my create table

```java
public SignShop insertSignShopSpec(Location location) {

        String query = "INSERT INTO `%s` (`location_x`, `location_y`, `location_z`, `location_world`, `custom_item`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
    
        try (
                Connection connection = this.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                        String.format(
                                query,
                                SignShopConstants.Databases.Mysql.Tables.SIGN_SHOP_TABLE_NAME
                        ),
                        Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS
                );
        ) {
    
            statement.setDouble(1, location.getX());
            statement.setDouble(2, location.getY());
            statement.setDouble(3, location.getZ());
            statement.setString(4, location.getWorld().getName());
            statement.setBoolean(5, false);
    
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
    
            return new SignShop(
                    resultSet.getInt("id"),
                    location,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    false,
                    null
            );
    
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    
        return null;
    }
```

I tried to use it `ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();`, but it resulted in an unexpected error

Answer (score 2):

To correctly retrieve the generated keys, it's essential to perform the insert operation using `statement.executeUpdate()` prior to accessing the generated keys with `statement.getGeneratedKeys()`.

```
int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();
ResultSet generatedKeys = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
```